# error in ggplot I can't generate bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

hello everyone I am trying to generate a bar chart by ggplot with values on top of the bar, but I can't get out of the first step.
follw my code:

```
a <- c (1,2,3,4)
b <- c (10,12,13,15)

d1 <- data.frame (a, b)

ggplot (d1, aes (x = a, y = b)) +
   geom_bar () +
   geom_text(stat = 'count', aes(label =..count.., hjust = -0.35))
```

show error: "Erro: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic."

how to solve?

Comment: Please don't add `rstudio` tag for questions related to only R. `rstudio` tag is reserved for questions related to the RStudio IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `geom_col` with `labels` as `b` value in `aes`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d1, aes (x = a, y = b, label = b)) +
  geom_col() + geom_text(vjust = -1)
```

[image]